# Monerod causes 404 error nginx after curl call

Tags: monerod, php

OS: Debian 10 Buster

APP: Nginx, php, mariadb, Monero

On my host I have a test script (test.php) to call my daemon (http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"0\",\"method\":\"get_info\"}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type: application/json'],
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   =>CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0
    ]);

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

This script shows true when monerod is OK (correct launch and synchronized with network).

But my problem is that when I launch monerod (synchronized with network), the test script (test.php) returns a 404 nginx error page.

In the nginx log, I have this:

```
2021/07/10 12:15:01 [error] 7667#7667: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.onion, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php8.0-fpm.sock", host: "example.onion"
```

My nginx website conf:

```
server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:84;
    server_name example.onion;
    access_log  off;
   
    location @blackhole {
        return 444;
    }
    
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.php;
    error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 =444 @blackhole;
        
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And when I close monerod (./monerod stop_daemon), the page 'test.php' becomes accessible and show false, because monerod is not syncronized.

I also test with zcash and no problem. I don't know why. This error happens no matter which port is used (18081 or 18087).

As a possible solution I add these three lines to 'location ~ .php$' in nginx (as it says Nginx + Php-fpm fastcgi upstream timed out):

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks for help

Edit:

Result of curl on the command line:

```
$ curl -vd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}' http://localhost:18081
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55cb5266ffb0)
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 18081 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:18081
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 46
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 46 out of 46 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
< Server: Epee-based
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Jul 2021 04:38:02 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

My nginx.conf :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 125;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

My nginx accces.log :
empty

My nginx error.log :

```
2021/07/23 04:32:13 [error] 540#540: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.onion, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock", host: "example.onion"
2021/07/23 04:34:04 [error] 540#540: *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.onion, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock", host: "example.onion"
2021/07/23 05:16:40 [error] 540#540: *7 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.onion, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock", host: "example.onion"
2021/07/23 05:17:55 [error] 540#540: *9 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.onion, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock", host: "example.onion"
2021/07/23 05:20:38 [error] 540#540: *11 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.onion, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock", host: "example.onion"
2021/07/23 05:23:34 [error] 540#540: *13 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.onion, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock", host: "example.onion"
```

My website nginx conf :

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:88;
 server_name example.onion;
  access_log off;

 location @blackhole {
   return 444;
 }

  
      root /var/www/html/;
      index index.html index.php;
error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 =404 @blackhole;
  

   location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
      #fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
      #fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
      #fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
   }
}
```

fastcgi-php.conf :

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Result of netstat -tlnp :

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:88              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:90              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18080           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/./monerod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18081         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/./monerod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18082         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/./monerod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: You should probably show the source of your php file in the question if you want help diagnosing what's wrong with it.

Comment: So isolate the problem. Can you call `curl -vd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}' http://localhost:18081/json_rpc` OK from the command line? If that works your PHP/nginx setup is the problem. If not, you're probably not synced properly.

Comment: I edit message about curl isolate, it won't work. I made this command after restart the server, restart monero and wait 'syncronised OK' message form monerod

Comment: You left off the `/json_rpc` when running the command.

Comment: It works by adding '/json_rpc' I have an http 200 response and the result of curl content.
SO the problem is in php/nginx, how to invest ?

Comment: Well your test.php file has no <?php ... ?> and doesn't return/output anything, which is probably why it's timing out.

Comment: there is the correct open tag for php, I didn't put in message. I use var_dump() for result. But with and without var_dumo() the page show 404 Not found  like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGqdX.png

Comment: So your fastcgi/nginx conf is wrong then. And as you only half provide the information, it's impossible to help you more.

Comment: I have add more informations, say me if you need more. Thanks for help

Comment: @jtgrassie Well, I see error log of php say me upstream connection timed out, I don't know fastcgi and How to resolve this!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be resolved by adding to

> /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php8.0.conf

this at end of file :

```
    ##
    # FastCGI PHP connection
    ##  

fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;  
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;    

  
    ##
    # FastCGI Cache
    ## 
fastcgi_cache phpcache;  
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;  
fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; 
add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
```

but this cause some problem detected by :

> $ sudo nginx -t

so I comment these lines who contain problem :

> fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;

> fastcgi_cache phpcache;

and the script seems work and I have answer of my curl request showed at screen.

Good diagnosis by @jtgrassie, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Error reappear, 
Reason : wrong url in my curl function.